# RMongo: Connect to mongoDB using port forwarding

Tags: r, mongodb, rmongodb, rmongo

I connect to a mongodb server using port forwarding like this:

```
ssh -i key.pem -Nf -L 27018:xx.xxx.xxx.xxx:27017 ubuntu@xx.xxx.xxx.xxx
mongo -u user -p pass --authenticationDatabase "db" --port 27018
```

Then I run R to connect and query the database:

```
library(RMongo)
mg1 <- mongoDbConnect(dbName = 'db', host = 'xx.xxx.xxx.xxx', port = 27018)
auth <- dbAuthenticate(rmongo.object = mg1, username = 'user', password = 'pass')
```

This gives me an error while authentication:

```
Error in .jcall(rmongo.object@javaMongo, "Z", "dbAuthenticate", username,  : 
  com.mongodb.MongoException$Network: IOException authenticating the connection
```

Without port forwarding, my credentials work:

```
library(RMongo)
mg1 <- mongoDbConnect(dbName = 'db', host = 'xx.xxx.xxx.xxx', port = 27017)
auth <- dbAuthenticate(rmongo.object = mg1, username = 'user', password = 'pass')
```

How do I set my port in `mongoDbconnect`?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Ok, this works. No need to put the host because now we are mapped to the `localhost`:

```
library(RMongo)
mg1 <- mongoDbConnect(dbName = 'db', host = 'localhost', port = '27018')
auth <- dbAuthenticate(rmongo.object = mg1, username = 'user', password = 'pass')
```